# Redirect User to a Specific URL using APACHE Shiro

Tags: java, apache, authentication, shiro

I have a requirement where i have 3 applications
App A
App B
App C

App A being the Gateway to App B and C

Now i want the user to land in App A's login page even if the user enters URL for App B 
How do i specify this in my shiro.ini

I have following setting as of now

[main]
                authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
                authc.successUrl = /dashboard
                authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

```
            [roles]
            ROLE_ADMIN = *

            [urls]
            /static/** = anon
            /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now suppose i want the login URL to be say www.facebook.com how do i do it?
I have tried to change it and it doesnt work if i change /login.jsp to www.facebook.com
Please help !!!

Comment: Hey guys solved it by over riding the setloginurl() method in org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean

Comment: Then answer your own question and accept that so the question doesn't stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys solved it by over riding the `setloginurl()` method in **org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean**